# Slideshow with animations using CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to create a slideshow, with 3 different animations that I created using css3. My problem is that I cannot infinitely repeat those animations.

I have 3 animations (3rd animation is on top of the 2nd, which is on top of the 1st).

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slideshow.css">
</head>
<body">
  <div id="animation">
    <img id="background1" src = "images/image1.png"/>
    <img id="img2" src="images/image2.png"/>
    <img id="img3" src="images/image3.png"/>
  </div>

   <div id="animation2" style = "position:absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px;">
      <img id="background2" src ="images/image4.png"/>
      <img id="img5" src="images/image5.png"/>
      <img id="img6" src="images/image6.png"/>
    </div>

   <div id="animation3" style ="position:absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px;">
        <img id="background3" src = "images/image7.png"/>
        <img id="img8" src="images/image8.png"/>
   </div>
<body>
```

Using css3, I have created some animations with the above images (code for animations is not provided because I don't think that is related to my question).
What I want now, is to create a slideshow, using those animations that will never end.

What I have until now is:

```
div#animation2 {
  width:1130px;
  height:222px;
  overflow:hidden;

  animation: slideshow1 20s;  
  animation-delay: 45s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

div#animation3 {
  width:1130px;
  height:222px;
  overflow:hidden;

  animation: slideshow2 20s;  
  animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}


@keyframes slideshow1 {
     0% {opacity: 1;} 5% {opacity: 0;} 100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes slideshow2 {
 0% {opacity: 1;} 5% {opacity: 0;} 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

So in summary, I want `animation3` to play and then fade-out, then `animation2` to play and then fade-out, `animation1` to play, then animation 3 should fade-in, play and then fade-out etc. etc.

Now I only have one iteration of the slideshow, and I want to have infinite iterations.

I tried to set `animation-iteration-count:` to `infinite` but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Did you try using a javascript? You can call your animation function evrytime after some set interval and that will run infinitely for you

Comment: I would like to avoid javascript.

Comment: Hi old-school do you have any demo for us?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/qmhzs2kh/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pic-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

figure {
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:0;
  /*animation*/
  
  animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: slideShow 24s linear infinite 0s;
}

.pic-1 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index:-1;
  background: url(http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-2 {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  background: url(http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/5.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-3 {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 12s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  background: url(http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/4.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-4 {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 18s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  background: url(http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* keyframes*/

@keyframes slideShow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transformm:scale(1);
  }    
 }

@-o-keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transformm:scale(1);    
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transformm:scale(1);    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideShow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transformm:scale(1);    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-wrapper">
  <figure class="pic-1"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-2"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-3"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-4"></figure>
</div>
```

Comment: i know it doesn't have animations in it but you could fiddle with it